# iterating over array with promises keeps rejecting

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I am trying to iterate over an array to receive data with $.get but i keep getting rejects,first i get paths from where the data should be received:

```
 function getFiles() {
        return $.get(URL + "/getdata.php");
    }

var testing= await getFiles();

testing=$.parseJSON(testing);
```

returns:

```
["12487.html", "46962.html"]
```

this works fine, but now i am trying to iterate like this:

```
var surveyData=[];
for(var i=0;i<testing.length;i++){
console.log('in loop   '+i)
surveyData.push(getHtml(testing[i]));

}

$.when(surveyData).done((...data)=>{
   console.log(data);

}).fail((e)=>{console.log('failed:'+e)})

async function getHtml(fileName){

return await $.get((URL + '/surveys/' + fileName, { "_": $.now() },'html'));

}
```

i have been trying to solve this for days now and of course i searched the web but couldnt find the solution,i keep getting:

> GET http://192.168.10.11:3000/html 404 (Not Found)

and

> Uncaught (in promise) {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ,
>   getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}

what i want is just an array filled the data coming from:

```
$.get((URL + '/surveys/' + fileName, { "_": $.now() },'html'));
```

but the index has to the same as index of testing, so when testing first item is 
123.html the data array first item has to be filled with data of 123.html and not get filled with data of 345.html for example.
appreciating any help

**edit**
the response from the promise is

> "Cannot GET /html↵"

i already got it working without promises but resulting in wrongly indexed data

```
 $.ajax({

        url: URL + "/getdata.php",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            serverfiles = $.parseJSON(data);
            if (serverfiles.length) {
                $.each(serverfiles, function (i, val) {
                    $.get(URL + '/surveys/' + val, { "_": $.now() }, function (html) {

                        //do something with html

                    }, 'html');
                });
            }

        },
        error: function (e) {

            console.log(e);
        },
        fail: function (e) {
            console.log('fail');
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
```

i am using Jquery 1.12.4 with cordova for Android & IOS

**UPDATE**

using HMR's code i get:

```
failed items:
failed: 12487.html error: 
Object { readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: getResponseHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders: getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader: setRequestHeader(), overrideMimeType: overrideMimeType(), statusCode: statusCode(), abort: abort(), state: state(), always: always(), then: then(), … }
failed: 46962.html error: 
Object { readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: getResponseHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders: getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader: setRequestHeader(), overrideMimeType: overrideMimeType(), statusCode: statusCode(), abort: abort(), state: state(), always: always(), then: then(), … }
successes: 
Array []
```

with following:

```
abort: function abort()
​
always: function always()
​
complete: function add()
​
done: function add()
​
error: function add()
​
fail: function add()
​
getAllResponseHeaders: function getAllResponseHeaders()
​
getResponseHeader: function getResponseHeader()
​
overrideMimeType: function overrideMimeType()
​
pipe: function then()
​
progress: function add()
​
promise: function promise()
​
readyState: 4
​
responseText: "Cannot GET /html\n"
​
setRequestHeader: function setRequestHeader()
​
state: function state()
​
status: 404
​
statusCode: function statusCode()
​
statusText: "Not Found"
​
success: function add()
​
then: function then()
​
__proto__: Object { … }
```

example of html data:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html><html><meta charset="UTF-8"><meta name="viewport"
 content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,
 minimum-scale=1, width=device-width"><head><title>Umfrage</title><link
 rel="stylesheet" href="http://mysite.de/s/css/Theme.css" /><link
 rel="stylesheet"
 href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css"
 /><script
 src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script><script
 src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script><script
 src="http://mysite.de/s/main.js"></script><noscript>JavaScript ist
 nicht aktiviert, bitte Aktivieren!</noscript></head><body><div
 data-role="page" id="survey" data-theme="a"><div data-role="header"
 data-position="fixed"><h2 id="title" style="text-align:center;">my
 title</h2></div><form action="" method="post" id="form"><hr
 id="hrid"><input type="submit" value="Abschicken" id="submit"><input
 type="hidden" value="my title" name="titlename"
 /></form></div></body></html>
```

Comment: Can you share the content of testing array?

Comment: Don't use `$.when` when you have `Promise.all`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is unrelated to promises. The problem is with the argument that you pass to `$.get`: it always evaluates to one argument with value "html" because of the comma operator which you (unconsciously?) use:

```
(URL + '/surveys/' + fileName, { "_": $.now() },'html')
```

The comma operator returns the value of the last element in the tuple. You probably did not intend to use that operator, but just wanted to pass 3 arguments to `$.get` instead of one. So remove one pair of parentheses so that the comma no longer acts as an operator but as a function argument separator:

```
URL + '/surveys/' + fileName, { "_": $.now() },'html'
```

Comment: Well spotted @trincot and well explained.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following can help you figure out what values are failing with what errors and what are successful:

```
function Fail(reason){this.reason=reason;};
const isFail = o=>(o&&o.constructor)===Fail;
const isNotFail = o=>!isFail(o);

Promise.all(
  testing.map(
    t=>getHtml(t).catch(err=>new Fail([err,t]))
  )
).then(//this will not result in rejected promises because catch will return fail object
  results=>{
    console.log("failed items:");
    results.filter(isFail).forEach(
      fail=>console.log("failed:",fail.reason[1],"error:",fail.reason[0])
    );
    console.log(
      "successes:",
      results.filter(isNotFail)
    );
  }
)
```

Also; if you want to use $.when with an array you should use it this way:

```
$.when.apply($,surveyData)
```

But depending of the version of jQuery you are using the deferred object behaves terrible (after version 2 it may be fine but I'm not sure). Better to use a decent Promise polyfill if you need to support browsers that don't have native promises.

Comment: it returns "Cannot GET /html↵"

Comment: @prince Can you please update your question with the code you're currently using (is it the code from my answer) and the complete console.log output of the code from my answer.

Comment: i updated the question, i cannot get the html data from the pages when using promise but without promise it works